# Multiple tenant in wso2is

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is tenant functionality useful for a saas web application? In wso2 docs the tenants are useful for multiple departments, but in my case I have multiple clientes with your own users.
How can I share my saas application between multiple tenant, if this tenant are isolated?

What’s the best way of use the wso2 capabilities for saas apps, using roles and access attributes (abac) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tenant functionality for your requirement. You can configure a service provider as the SaaS application, then that application can be access by all other tenant members.

[image]

By default, the SaaS Application check box is disabled, which means the web application is not shared among tenants so only users in the current tenant (the one you use to define the service provider) will be allowed to log into the web application. Alternatively, if you enabled the SaaS Application check box, that means this web application is shared among tenants so users from any tenant will be allowed to log into the web application.

You can refer here [for](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider#AddingandConfiguringaServiceProvider-Addingaserviceprovider) more info

---

> What’s the best way of use the wso2 capabilities for saas apps, using roles and access attributes (abac) ?

If you meant to configure the authentication mechanism for the saas apps using roles and access attributes, you can use the [Adaptive Authentication](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Adaptive+Authentication) feature. This feature will allow you to control the authentication/ authorization flow using simple javascript